# Expo App with zoomed Icon after installed

Tags: react-native, expo

I made a simple app to convert units using Expo.
However, the icon is zoomed in once installed.

[image]

It was supposed to be like this

[image]

This is a 1024x1024 image.

The source code of my app is here -> https://github.com/Elson0509/peuc

The app in the Google Play Store is here -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.elsonramos.peuc

Someone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest Android versions support adaptive icons which scaled well for different icon layouts - Square, Round, Circle, and more.

Expo Team provide a template to design adaptive icon
https://www.figma.com/community/file/1155362909441341285

Answer (score 1):

New link for the Expo Team template: https://www.figma.com/community/file/1155362909441341285